# c++ set different symbol visibility to different users

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm writing a c++ lib, say `mylib`. For most users they only need symbol visibility for a few public APIs. I release `mylib` through a `.so` dynamic library. But I have another code repo, say `mylib_builder`, which builder the objects in `mylib` and serialize those objects into disk. `mylib_builder` requires more symbol visibility, since it might need access to some very internal objects in `mylib`.

The reason I make two separate libs is that the `mylib_builder` itself is very complicated and has a huge codebase, so separating them might make it easier to manage the whole project.

The problem is that normal users and `mylib` have different symbol visibility requirements, how can I achieve that? Or maybe separating `mylib` and `mylib_builder` is not a good practise?

Comment: You always have the option to make a basic library that both user bases need. Adding 1, 2 or both on top for the extras _should_ be easy.